# How to query on fields returned from painless script_fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I am new to ES and need some help. Can someone please tell me if there is a way to query on field returned from script_fields? Below is the script_fields I am using:

```
  "script_fields": {
    "active": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
        some scripting logic to return 1 or 0 based on a condition
        """
      }
    }
  }
}

The above code is returning:
"hits" : [
      {
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "gHMczncBe9m3adljCcTq",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : {
            "email" : "xxx.yyy@yyy.com",
            "firstname" : "XXX",
            "lastname" : "YYY"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "active" : [
            0
          ]
        }
      },{
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "gHMczncBe9m3adljCcTq",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : {
            "email" : "xxx.yyy@yyy.com",
            "firstname" : "XXX",
            "lastname" : "YYY"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "active" : [
            1
          ]
        }
      }
]
```

Is there a way to count the documents which have active as 1?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of ES are you running?

Comment: @Val: I am using ES - 7.5.0

Answer (score 2):

If you're using version 7.11 and up you can leverage [runtime fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html) instead of script fields

```
POST my-index/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "active": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
        some scripting logic to return 1 or 0 based on a condition
        """
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "active": 1
    }
  }
}
```

If you're using 7.10 and earlier, then you're out of luck. The only way to achieve what you want is to create the `active` field in each of your document, for instance using the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) and then issuing the query against the new field.